# import時の別名のつけ方のマナー

Tags: python, python3, coding-style

## 前提

`numpy`を import するとき、

```
import numpy as np
```

というように書くことが多いと思います

この別名のつけ方に関してですが、アルファベット2文字は見たことがあります
しかし、アルファベット1文字は見たことがありません

## 質問

```
import crossover as x
```

のように、アルファベット1文字まで短くすることはマナー違反でしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

これは、プログラムを書いている人の主観に依存する問題です。もっと言うと、どのようなコーディングスタイルに従っているかによります。そのスタイルにこのことが書かれているかどうかと、書かれていない場合、チームとしてどのような方針にするかを確認してください。

少なくとも、Python を書いている人全体が共有している明文化された「マナー」は私の知る限り存在しません。たとえば PEP 8 にも [import について書かれている節があります](https://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/index.html#import)が、as の名前については書かれていません。

ただ、「書かれていない」ことがそのまま「許されている」ことを意味するわけでは無いので、チームとしての方針を確認してください。個人的には Python でモジュール名を 1 文字にするのは避けていますが、`import math as m` のようにすることを好むスタイルもあるようです。

もっと具体的に、「○○というコーディングスタイルにおいてどう扱われているか？」というご質問にして頂けると、より詳しい回答が集まるかもしれません。

Comment: >これは、プログラムを書いている人の主観に依存する問題です。
>少なくとも、Python を書いている人全体が共有している「マナー」は私の知る限り存在しません。
以上のことがわかれば十分です
ご回答ありがとうございました